# 64-bit structure is actually padded to 12 bytes

Tags: c, memory, struct, sizeof, bit-fields

Consider the structure below, where the sum of bitfield sizes are 64-bit. Why does `sizeof` say this structure is 12 bytes, when it should be 8?

```
typedef struct wl_Ls {
    unsigned int    total:17;
    unsigned int    used:17;
    unsigned int    entrySize:17;
    _Bool           point:1;
} wl_Ls;
```

[SOLUTION:] Using a 64-bit type fixes for first 2 or 3 members fixes it. Explanation is in the answer marked as Solution

Comment: What does `sizeof` say for the individual elements on that architecture?

Comment: What happens if you change the `_Bool` to `unsigned int` for `point`?  IIRC, adjacent bit fields need to have matching types.

Comment: 17+17 doesn't fit in `unsigned int`. Try with `uint64_t`.

Comment: I suspect it is how word addresses are being set for each member. See the following for discussion: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_bitfields

Comment: @interjay, it does work, but it soft of breaks the point of using bit fields if I'll need to do logic operations anyway.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Please don't refer people to references written by ESR. They are consistently only about 70% accurate, plus 30% *disastrously wrong*, and it can be very hard to disentangle the wrong parts from the correct parts.

Comment: @Wispy: I think the idea is `uint64_t total:17; uint64_t used:17;` and so forth.  No logic operations needed.

Comment: @NateEldredge, that seemed to have actually worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitfields are not always guaranteed to be packed tightly together. Two of the situations where the compiler is allowed to insert padding between bitfields are: when two consecutive bitfields are not the same type, and when a bitfield doesn't fit into the number of bits that are still available in an "allocation unit" of the bitfield's type.

Assuming `unsigned int` is 32 bits, all three pairs of consecutive bitfields in your structure qualify for at least one of those situations.

Comment: If I were to remove `point` member, it would still allocate 12 bytes, at least on a Unix system with GCC. The "allocation unit" should be 8 bytes in this case, shouldn't it? If not are there some extra bytes allocated for bit-fields?

Comment: @Wispy Each member is 4 bytes.

Comment: It can't combine two 17-bit fields into the same `unsigned int`. So it has to use a separate `unsigned int` for each member. 3x4 = 12 bytes.

Comment: The C standard does not impose any relationship between the type a bit-field is declared with and the storage unit. Regardless of whether `unsigned int` is 32 bits or not, the C implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit 17 bits or larger for a 17-bit bit-field. It also does not say padding may be inserted (bits may be skipped) when consecutive bit-fields are declared with different types. It says if there is enough space in the storage unit, then the following bit-field is packed into that unit, and no mention of type is made (C 2018 6.7.2.1 11).

Comment: @EricPostpischil If memory serves, that is a change relative to some older edition of the standard. Couldn't tell you which older edition presently, though.

Comment: C 1990 6.5.2 unnumbered paragraph, C 1999 6.7.2.1 10, and C 2018 6.7.2.1 11 are identical:

Comment: “An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.”